# React: change values inside multi step form with FieldArray methods

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form, formwizard, react-final-form-arrays

I've a **multi step form** made with `react-final-form` that makes use of `FieldArray`. 
The end user can add X number of typologies of rooms, and according to that number the next step will generate arrays of rooms.

Here's a [live demo - codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-form-procedure-8cr93?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fsteps%2FStepRooms.js&theme=dark)

Now when it comes to the second step (the rooms configuration) I need to set default values in an ongoing process: 
when the user choose a max number of adults the value of max children should be setted that number minus 1.

I'm using `<OnChange>` component inside the `FieldArray` (calling the `fields.update()` method).
It works but the problem is that it changes all the values inside the object. You can check this behaviour on the demo above.

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, beautiful form! You were very close. I've moved the `<OnChange/>` component into `RoomRow` and used a `<Field/>` to get the `onChange` for the `max_children` field.

[image: Edit beautiful-form-procedure]

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late response. It works! (I had to remove the `<OnChange />` component from StepRooms.js in your example, that's the reason it wasn't working at first).

Comment: may I ask you a related problem with this form? I tried to create a condition to render entire pages (but can't access values inside the `Wizard` class). The only way I found is generating a condition within the `Wizard.Page` method, since I figured out how to access values inside the pages): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398923/react-final-form-make-conditions-according-to-form-values